# Cassandra: How to find node with matching token for restoring to newer cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I want to restore data from an existing cluster to newer cluster. I want to do so using the method, that of, copying the snapshot SSTables from old cluster to keyspaces of newer cluster, as explained in http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_snapshot_restore_t.html.

The same document says, " ... the snapshot must be copied to the correct node with matching tokens". What does it really mean by "node with matching tokens"?

My current cluster is of 5 nodes and for each node num_tokens: 256. I am gonna create another cluster with same no of nodes and num_tokens and same schema. Do I need to follow the ring order while copying SSTables to newer cluster? How do I find matching target node for a given source node?

I tried command "nodetool ring" to check if I can use token values to match. But this command gives all the tokens for each host. How can I get the single token value (which determines the position of the node in the ring)? If I can get it, then I can find the matching nodes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vnodes its really hard to copy the sstables over correctly because its not just one assigned token that you have to reassign, but 256. To do what your asking you need to do some additional steps described http://datascale.io/cloning-cassandra-clusters-fast-way/. Basically reassign the 256 tokens of each node to a new node in other cluster so the ring is the same. The article you listed describes loading it on the same cluster which is a lot simpler because you dont have to worry about different topologies. Worth noting that even in that scenario, if a new node was added or a node was removed since the snapshot it will not work.

Safest bet will be to use sstableloader, it will walk through the sstable and distribute the data in the appropriate node. It will also open up possibility of making changes without worrying if everything is correct. Also it ensures everything is on the correct nodes so no worries about human errors. Each node in the original cluster can just run sstableloader on each sstable to the new cluster and you will parallelize the work pretty well.

I would strongly recommend you use this opportunity to decrease the number of vnodes to 32. The 256 default is excessive and absolutely horrible for rebuilds, solr indexes, spark, and most of all it *ruins* repairs. Especially if you use incremental repairs (default), the additional ranges will cause much more anticompactions and load. If you use sstableloader on each sstable it will just work. Increasing your streaming throughput in the cassandra.yaml will potentially speed this up a bit as well.

If by chance your using OpsCenter this backup and restore to new cluster is automated as well.